# Use docker-swarm with dokku

Tags: docker, dokku, docker-swarm

The swarm document here https://docs.docker.com/swarm/ tell us that

> Because Docker Swarm serves the standard Docker API, any tool that
>   already communicates with a Docker daemon can use Swarm to
>   transparently scale to multiple hosts. Supported tools include, but
>   are not limited to, the following:
>
> Dokku Docker Compose Krane Jenkins

So how can I use Dokku with docker-swarm to support multi hosts?

Comment: Have you seen this documenation? http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/dockerfiles/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dokku maintainer here.

I have *zero* idea where the Docker folks got the idea that Dokku works out of the box with Docker Swarm. Hell, I hadn't even thought of that until recently.

Anyhow, [here](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/1795) is an issue where we are tracking docker swarm support. It might be coming up in an official release soon, though I don't think its possible at the moment without futzing about in the core.